# How to remove multiple instances of the app

Tags: android, url, android-intent, android-activity

I made an app that create and listen custom url. My problem is the multiple instances of the app. For example I create a url and send it to my friend through sms. After that I open that sms (that contains url) in my app. This create a new instance of my app that open this url. I want that there must be only one instance at a time. How will I achieve this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `android:launchMode="singleTop"` to your Activity in **AndroidManifest.xml** which opens URL. For example:

```
<activity android:name="com.abc.MainActivity" android:label="app_name"
          android:launchMode="singleTop">
```

Moreover, if you like to catch new `Intent` then override the following method in your activity code:

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    setIntent(intent);   //set new intent as current intent
}
```

Comment: What I understand is that this will maintain only one existence of any activity in the stack. isn't?

Comment: yes, but will also allow you to get new intent requests via `onNewIntent` method.

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:launchMode="singleTask"` to your `Activity` in `AndroidManifest.xml`. For more information, please check this document on [LaunchMode of an Activity](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html).